# npm run dev is not working missing script how do I fix this

Tags: npm

I have downloaded a zip file of a Barba project, unzipped opened it in VS then npm install yarn and then npm run dev.. I get error missing script dev. What am I missing ?

```
 "name": "barba-starter-template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple starter template for setting up a ECMAScript 6 project with barba.js and webpack.",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
```

Comment: Do you think it _does_ define a script named `dev`? Without a [mre] there's little we can do to help.

Comment: Well Im following  a tutorial,  He explains it to be set up and accessed this way.

Comment: Then ask the author of the tutorial, who will have the context we lack, but you haven't provided enough information here. Check the `package.json` file to see what scripts _are_ defined.

Comment: I have edited tio include the Json pkg to which i included script for node